# Java: Quickest way to create a temp file with column header

Tags: java

I need to create a temporary file with column headers. And I need to do it in the most efficient (fastest, least computational intensive) manner.

I notice I can do it either by

```
Path file = Files.createTempFile(arguments);
```

or:

```
File f = new File(filename_str)
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f,true);
```

With the second method, I know that I can just check if `f` exists and `f` is not a directory, then I can use a for loop to write out the column headers.

However, with the first method, I believe I would have to create a `file` object and check if the file exists, if not, then I do `createTempFile` and write the column headers. This seems a bit convoluted because I would essentially be using the `File` and `FileWriter` as well as `createTempFile`. Then what is the point of using `createTempFile` in the first place?

I am wondering what is the difference in terms of performance between these 2 methods ? Obviously, one is a path object and the second method involves a File object and FileWriter object. But which method is faster or more efficient than the other ?

Comment: Creating the file physically on disk will take the most time I think. Why bother here for efficiency?

Answer (score 2):

java.nio.file.Path is the more modern and reliable approach.  Always prefer it over java.io.File.

Performance is irrelevant here.  The difference won’t be noticeable.  What takes time is creation of the file, and that has nothing to do with which Java method or class is used.

createTempFile is *guaranteed* to create a file with a name that no existing file uses.  That is pretty much the purpose of the method.

Comment: @TomkaKoliada Working with files will certainly affect performance, but the choice of java.io.File versus java.nio.file.Path will not make a difference in performance (unless the choice causes one to inadvertently misuse the API, for example forgetting to use a buffered stream).